# WKWebView loading local HTML require HTTPServer

Tags: ios, swift3, wkwebview

I have website download to the iOS device locally run in WKWebView. I checked the website written to load JSON to construct the page. It requires an HTTP server support. I have a question that can WKWebView can support this scenario and how to code it? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing a similar issue. UIWebView never had this problem, as it seemed to run a server in the background, so therefore constructing a page through json was never an issue. WKWebView, however, does not seem to be able to do this. One possible solution is to use a framework called **Swifter** that can be installed using **CocoaPods**. It basically emulates a server, so may make loading json in WKWebView a possibility.

https://github.com/httpswift/swifter

However, trying to use it myself, it seems to have problems with the latest Xcode 9 and Swift 4. If it gets sorted soon, it may solve your issue.